# Range extender with 2 almost identical mac addresses on the router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, mac-address

I hope it's the right section to post this question. On the wifi router I see 2 entries for my tp-link range extender with the same IP.
One is with the correct MAC and I see the IP v4 and the IP v6.
The second entry is with the same (correct) device name, the same IP v4 but a slightly different mac address (the first couple is not 00 but 02, the rest is equal) and I see 2,4 Ghz (in the first record it's not indicated).
What could this be due to?
Best regards

Comment: Probably 2.4 and 5GHz.  If it isn't too secret maybe tell us the model of TP-Link you have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the extender has both 2.4GHz and 5GHz band support then that's expected, since physically they are different radios and each needs its own MAC address.